# How do you get back Recent Documents feature that was in XP on Windows7?

Tags: windows-7

How do you get back Recent Documents feature that was in XP on Windows7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the start menu button,

Click Properties,

Click the start menu tab,

Click the customize button.

Check the "Recent Items" radio button,

Click ok,

Click ok

Comment: Is that not the recent items that were accessed on the start menu?  Not recent documents that were opened?

Comment: Nope its not, try it and see